# After WW2, why did Stalin let Finland off with some loss of territory rather than occupation and crushing reparations?

Tags: world-war-two, stalin, finland

Finland did lose 10% of its territory and 20% of its industry according to Wikipedia, but given Stalin's paranoia, why was it not occupied by Soviet troops?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_War

Comment: Stalin tried, and failed.

Comment: You are confusing the two wars (ww2 and the winter war).

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: You meant the [Continuation War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation_War), and the [Moscow Amistice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Armistice). Same thing, really -- Finland simply wasn't defeated wholesale.

Comment: Moishe Cohen & Denis de Bernardy, I wasn't confusing the wars.
DevSolar, thanks for the comment / links; I hadn't heard the term "continuation war" before.  Denis de Bernardy... just... jeez.

Comment: This is a very good question and should not have been closed. After the continuation war, the Soviet Union was able to force Finland's absolute surrender and force them to attack their previous allies. They may have cost the Soviets dearly for their victory, but they were absolutely "defeated wholesale". In other cases in Eastern Europe where Russia had similar power other countries they annexed them, in the case of the Baltics, or made them into satellite states such as Poland. The fact that they didn't in Finland is something worthy of an answer.